# Macomb County/City of Warren GIS data

Tags: geospatial

I am looking to download datasets or shapefiles of parcel data, zoning districts, schools, childcares, recreational facilities, public libraries, and public parks for Macomb county Michigan. I found this GIS data viewer that has all the data I need but I cannot download any of it! Here is the data viewer http://gis.macombgov.org/flexviewer2/

I sent the county an email, but they have not responded to me yet. So my questions are where else can I find this type of data? and would they give me the data if I file a FOIA request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that site requires flash, which I'm not going to install.
here's some data about Macomb County.
https://www.mcgi.state.mi.us/mgdl/?rel=cext&action=Macomb

There's also the Michigan Open Data Portal, however you're going to have to pull Macomb County's data out of each dataset:
http://gis.michigan.opendata.arcgis.com/

EDIT:
To answer question in comments about FOIA'ing for it, I seriously doubt they'll care, after coming across this:
http://ped.macombgov.org/sites/default/files/content/pdfs/Macomb%20County%20Enhanced%20Access%20to%20Public%20Records%20Policy_0.pdf

You can view more info about each set here:
http://gis.macombgov.org/portal1/home/gallery.html#c=organization&o=modified

You can also tinker around with the API, I've had some success with this approach, but few and far between. I snagged the .kmz file from here, but they have networked links so they don't work if you download them. This seems like something that is an easy fix, but I've yet to figure it out or find a solution.
http://gis.macombgov.org/arcgis1/rest/services/FLEX2/Community_Map/MapServer

You can use the individual dataset pages to view detailed information about the data being rendered, which can then be copied. I've had mixed results with this, but even the wins were manual-labor intense and hair-pulling maddening. I tinkered with one for you, only realizing after the fact they do not include lat/lon:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H1bDDP9fDF0tE4jjmxuPPbE1pRVfIRQfoNHh_yo5G9U/edit#gid=0

Last Chance Resort: I noticed in the portal that they have an older Flexviewer setup...no clue if this is doable, but perhaps you can rip through that files source code and look for the data or urls or paths to things that you seek.
http://gis.macombgov.org/flexmobile2/

Comment: Checked out your two links but none of the data I need is available through those sites. Would you know if a FOIA request would have grounds to obtain the data i need from macomb county?

Comment: see edit to answer

Comment: hey a few things, how did you snag the kmz file using the api? using python?  and where did you view the individual datasets for the data to be copied? did you open it in arcgis desktop then just simply copied the info?

Comment: snag kmz via api - go here and click on google earth http://gis.macombgov.org/arcgis1/rest/services/FLEX2/Community_Map/MapServer    using the browser. i would never use arcgis. friends don't let friends.

Comment: why dont you like arcgis(besides for the price)?

Comment: their commitment to openness is suspect. particularly around open gov, open data, open formats and open web.